# What is the most optimal arrangement of if statements?

Tags: performance

If I have for example:

```
if(a<50){A}    
if(a<20){B}
if(a<10){C}
```

For this set, where the number represents the percentage of time a certain statement will run, and they all not mutually exclusive, in what way should I arrange my if statements in order to make the program as efficient as possible?
What I want to achieve is, if a = 5 I only want C to run, if I get 15, I only want B to run.

I am well aware of how to create this, what I want is the most efficient way to do it. Assume A,B,C... take the same computing. Also no side effects are ignored since if I run C, it will overwrite what A and B did.

Thank you

Comment: Are you asking about a particular language?

Answer (score 0):

Your post is self contradictory. You say the cases are:

> not mutually exclusive

But then you say:

> if a = 5 I only want C to run, if I get 15, I only want B to run

That *is* mutually exclusive, which you can achieve thusly:

```
     if(a<10){C} // do C and only C if a < 10
else if(a<20){B} // do B and only B if a >= 10 && a < 20
else if(a<50){A} // do A and only A if a >= 20 && a < 50
```

Comment: I might have miss explained myself, the end result is mutually exclusive in the sense that the results from A get overwritten if B in ran

Comment: You said "if I get 15, I *only want B to run*". If that's now what you meant, you should change your original post. As it is, it makes no sense.

Answer (score 0):

This is micro-optimisation. You're comparing the performance of a minuscule portion of code in isolation. Any decent compiler will optimise this extensively. Even if you could improve on the performance it is likely that you'll have wasted far more time on the exercise than you will ever recover in improved performance. As with all optimisations the only way to be sure is to profile the different options. This is not a worthwhile exercise for this code.